# Apache Solr indexing with RDBMS-like references

Tags: mysql, solr, solrj

Can anyone let me know how to index a particular field in solr as foreign key? I will be indexing from a MySQL database.

Indexing a field as a primary key was done by just specifying that field as a unique key in `Schema.xml`, but I want to index a field as foreign key.

Comment: No need for an all-caps title. It's already bold and of a bigger font size.

Answer (score 2):

Solr Wiki says:

> For people who are used to SQL, it's important to note that Joins in
>   Solr are not really equivalent to SQL Joins because no information
>   about the table being joined "from" is carried forward into the final
>   result. A more appropriate SQL analogy would be an "inner query".

You must understand that Solr isn't an RDBMS and it is pretty much flat structured. You can use Solr as a text search engine. Before getting into it, you have to decide what you exactly want to achieve. [Here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/WhyUseSolr)'s a couple of things to differentiate between Solr and an RDBMS:

Specifying a unique key in Solr is to distinguish between the documents. You cannot hold references to other documents in Solr as any other SQL does. You have to write an import handler to import data from MySQL, which will convert/restructure the MySQL records into a flattened/denormalized structure on which you can index any or every field. And even if you want to store documents of different types and want to establish relationships among them, you can use [joins](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Join) (and [here](http://www.slideshare.net/lucenerevolution/grouping-and-joining-in-lucenesolr)'s how you use grouping and joining) or you will have to write an external application that does the mapping when queried on and returns the related documents (Which I seriously don't think is a best idea, as it will be an overkill for Solr when there are enormous number of documents).

Comment: You're welcome @user2852305. And if you think you got your answer, you can accept the above answer! :)